# Can't find the IP address which should in NAT CIDR

Tags: windows, virtualbox, nat

I use virtualbox created a centos7 vm, and there is a nat network adapter with dhcp mode.

after I started the vm, it get the IP `10.0.2.15/24`, and it can access Internet via gateway `10.0.2.2`,

[image]

but however in my host(win10), I don't find a IP address which in CIDR `10.0.2.0/24`.

[image] (this is a windows XP snapshot replace of my win10, I post here for hiding my PC information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox NAT is done in userspace, *independently* from the host OS – the `VBoxNetNAT.exe` process contains the entire "router" and NAT engine. Packets from the guest cause VBoxNetNAT.exe to send packets over your host's Ethernet interface.

(Actually VBoxNetNAT doesn't even send raw IP packets – when it receives e.g. TCP SYN packets from a guest, VirtualBox uses a normal TCP socket to establish a new connection to the destination. When you create a "port forward" rule in VirtualBox, that's not an actual DNAT rule – it just makes VBoxNetNAT itself listen for connections on 127.0.0.1, and when it receives a connection it generates fresh TCP SYN packets for the guest.)

Comment: Also, from the screenshots, I believe you may have accidentally installed Windows XP into your host instead of Windows 10

Comment: so the host cannot communicate to the vm, right?

Comment: They kind of can, but the host has to go through the same "port forward" rules, and has to connect to `127.0.0.1` where VBoxNetNAT is listening – you _cannot_ directly reach 10.0.2.x from the host. In the opposite direction, when the guest wants to reach the host, it can do so through `10.0.2.1` (which is forwarded to the host's "localhost").